# Andre's solution to the ballot problem

Tags: combinatorics

Andre's solution was discussed in the link below:

[About André's original solution to the Ballot problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279449/about-andr%C3%A9s-original-solution-to-the-ballot-problem)

The solution from Marc Van Leeuwen includes the following simplification, can someone please explain how this was calculated?

$$\binom{p+q}p-2\binom{p+q-1}p=\frac{p-q}{p+q}\binom{p+q}p$$

$$\binom{p+q}p-2\frac{q}{p+q}\binom{p+q}p$$

$$=\binom{p+q}p(1-\frac{2q}{p+q})$$

$$=\binom{p+q}p(1-\frac{2q}{p+q})$$

$$=\binom{p+q}p\frac{p+q-2q}{p+q})$$

$$=\frac{p-q}{p+q}\binom{p+q}p$$

Thanks Baz

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $\binom{p+q-1}{p}=\frac{q}{p+q}\binom{p+q}{p}$. This fact can be proved by converting both binomial coefficients to factorials, via $\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.